# Phonegap app development advice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have just finished my first iOS app using Phonegap, jQuery and jQuery mobile and ran into several issues during development. The main ones were performance issues on devices, unreliable video playback related to auto play, annoying white screen during transitions and horizontal scrolling issues. I was hoping that some people out there, with more experience than myself, could suggest better tools to use, i have looked at Sencha touch and jQTouch, but have no idea what direction to take.

Any advice would be greatly beneficial.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you try to fix the issues instead?

Comment: Have done. What i am asking is for different options for developing mobile apps, preferably something that will cause me less stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use sencha-touch 2 to develop such phone gap applications.
I was also very much annoyed with the performance issues of jquery mobile with phone gap especially the white screen during transition issues but when i tried sencha,it  was very impressive. And i am sure u would like it too.
its also easy to learn [here.](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion and i look forward to giving it a go

Comment: i think this will be helpful to u http://floatlearning.com/2011/03/developing-better-phonegap-apps/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know/want to use Obj-C, Titanium is the best way to go http://appcelerator.com

Comment: ye, sorry forgot to mention that i really don't want to learn Objective C

Comment: that's why I recommended Titanium

Answer (score 1):

All of the frameworks out there will get the job done, but getting the job done right is another things. I use a custom built framework and performance is actually quite good, even on Android 2.2.2!

You need to understand that CSS transitions will save you, on iOS you can get hardware acceleration. Forget animating using jQuery.

On that note using jQuery is fine, Zepto can be even better - they have similar syntax so it's easy to jump into Zepto.

Do not approach app building like you would a website - you need to be considerate to the environment. Processing power is much more limited for mobile - so some things that work great on desktop will not do well in mobile. Consider images vs drawing with code. Use Ajax to load in pages vs having everything on one page ( this kills your processor )

Also there is added benefit in learning native code - using them together can be quite useful - using native to do heavy lifting...

The frameworks do work, but they are bulky and if you're like me you like control. I like to know every line of code in a project so if a problem does arise I know exactly how to fix it...

just my thoughts!